# Storing passport facebook session in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to setup Facebook authentication following the example on passport-facebook GitHub, but I am not getting the session to store. As soon as I log into Facebook and am redirected back to "/", there is no evidence that I am logged in in my application. Since it is directing me back to the successRedirect route when my login is indeed successful on Facebook, it seems that I am missing code needed to save the session.

In my app.js file I have the following.

```
       var express = require("express"),
            bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
            passport = require("./auth/local"),
            FacebookStrategy = require("passport-facebook"),
            LinkedInStrategy = require("passport-linkedin"),
            GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google"),
            cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
            session = require("express-session"),
            fbStrategy = require("./auth/facebook");
    var  app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('./auth/facebook', 
  fbStrategy.authenticate('facebook'
));

app.get('./auth/facebook/callback',
  fbStrategy.authenticate('facebook', {
      successRedirect: "/",
      failureRedirect: '/login' })
);
```

In the route /auth/facebook.js I have the following code

```
   var passport = require('passport'),
        FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook'),
        authHelpers = require("./_helpers");

    var init = require('./passport');

    init();

    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: [...],
        clientSecret: [...],
        callbackURL: "callbackurl",
        //for profFields look here for definitions... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user
        profileFields: ['id','first_name','last_name','gender','political','verified','currency','birthday']
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  knex('user').select('email','user_id').where({facebookID:profile.id})
  .then((user) => {
    if (user.length==0) {
      knex('user').insert({
      email: profile.emails[0].value, 
      facebookID:profile.id,
      firstname: profile.name.givenName, 
      lastname: profile.name.familyName
      })
      return done(null,user);
    } else {
      return done(null, user);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {console.log("problem near line 24 in auth/facebook.js... "+err); return done(err); });
       }
    }));



module.exports = passport;
```

My database configuration is working fine everywhere else, so I did not include the configuration code/file in the above snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code here on https://github.com/rupalipemare/Todo-Demo, wherein there is complete example demonstrating passport authentication using local , facebook, and google.